# How to append a subdirectory to every url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This might be a two part question. I am trying to set up a 302 redirect as this is a stop gap in a migration I am working on. I am trying to go from:

http://www.domain.com/recipes/4068956-Sausage-Stuffed-Mushrooms to 
http://www.domain.com/blog/recipes/sausage-stuffed-mushrooms

http://www.domain.com/recipes/4184093-Not-So-Fried-Zucchini to
http://www.domain.com/blog/recipes/not-so-fried-zucchini

So the two parts. One I need to append '/blog/' to every url. And ideally I would like to remove the random id number before each recipe. I am not sure if this is possible. But I am at a total loss at doing anything more complicated then a simple 301 redirect in htaccess.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Redirect in your htaccess that redirects urls from older version to new.

You need to use RedirectMatch here since it uses regex to match a dynmic uri.

```
RedirectMatch ^/recipes/([0-9]+)-(.+)$ /blog/recipes/$2
```

This will redirect :

```
/recipes/([0-9]+)-(.+)$

/recipes/anynumbers-anychar
```

to

```
/blog/recipes/$2

/blog/recipes/anychar
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I kept trying to do this via RewriteCond.